# Builder implementation

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, oop, visual-c++

I'm trying to implement a builder in C++, by using the 'piggyback' method calls approach, but the Visual C++ compiler throws an error saying:

`Error  6   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '->' c:\users\owner\desktop\user\t\t\algebratopic.cpp    20  1   MathTutor`

Using the following Code:

```
Question * test = new QuestionBuilder()
        ->withQuestionText("(4y + 5x)2 = ")
        ->withCorrectAnswer("16y2 + 25x2 + 40xy")
        ->buildQuestion();
```

Each call to with* methods, return the question builder instance, and buildQuestion returns a question* object.

Any ideas?

Comment: Didn't solve the issue

Comment: Why are you using manual memory management here (and leaking memory)? Furthermore, this code is clearly not enough to diagnose the code. Post a minimal working example to illustrate the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put parentheses around the `new` expression, and change `->` to `.` as appropriate. For example:

```
struct Foo
{
    Foo & f() { return *this; }
    Foo & g() { return *this; }
    Foo * build() { return this; }
};

int main()
{
    Foo * p = (new Foo())->f().g().build();
}
```